# Helm chart to use secrets from cert-manager

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I want to automate the use a certificate, that is created by `cert-manager` as documented [here](https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/certificate/), in a Helm chart. For example, the YAML below.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
  labels:
    app: mypod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mypod
      image: repo/image:0.0.0
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumeMounts:
        - name: certs
          mountPath: /etc/certs
          readOnly: true
      ports:
        - containerPort: 4443
          protocol: TCP
  volumes:
    - name: certs
      secret:
        secretName: as_created_by_cert-manager
```

How do I submit the YAML for getting a `Certificate` from `cert-manager` and then plugin the generated `Secret` into the `Pod` YAML above, in a Helm chart?

Comment: You should be able to write the YAML for the `Certificate` in the same chart, typically in its own file.  I'd expect it would work to create them together, the generated Pod would show up as "Pending" in `kubectl get pods` output until cert-manager actually creates the matching Secret.

Comment: Please add as answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting David's comment as a community wiki answer as requested by the OP:

> You should be able to write the YAML for the Certificate in the same
>   chart, typically in its own file. I'd expect it would work to create
>   them together, the generated Pod would show up as "Pending" in kubectl
>   get pods output until cert-manager actually creates the matching
>   Secret. – David Maze